# Where are all Ubuntu resources linked together?

Tags: development, community, brainstorm

There's a lot of pages if on wants to contribute to Ubuntu:

- http://harvest.ubuntu.com/
- http://developer.ubuntu.com/
- http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/
- http://askubuntu.com
- http://ubuntuforums.org
- https://lists.ubuntu.com/
- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu

How are they all interlinked and how do they facilitate organisation of the community?
Are they all equally watched by developers?
What is the first hand portal to submit improvements and get ones voice heard?

I find it currently a bit confusing.

Thanks in advance for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

You left out a few such as wiki and irc =)

It is a large community and people tend to gravitate to their interests, some prefer forums, others irc, others ask Ubuntu. Developers seem to prefer Launchpad, well at least that is how they follow bug reports.

With that said, there are ongoing discussions about community building / coordination including summit meetings

http://uds.ubuntu.com/

And between UDS meetings people seem to be coalescing on irc, join

#ubuntu-community-team

#ubuntu-beginners-team

It is great to see people continue to become involved in the Community, what would you like to contribute ? If you can answer that we can better direct you to some entry points.

Comment: I just wanted to express that these resources are all very skattered and it's not ieasy to find them either.

Sometimes usere have ideas that are a bit more abstract than just a bug/blueprint. Where to discuss this?
Where is my voice best heard?



I think like using Launchpad for specific development and packaging.

so just posted: [Where is a suitable forum to discuss the use of Lunchpad for development?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/98232/where-is-a-suitable-forum-to-discuss-the-use-of-lunchpad-for-development)