# What is a suitable place to ask for help when getting PPA build errors?

Tags: ppa, development, launchpad, recipe

I am trying to work on some PPA recipes.
As I am getting build errors I am seeking help from the community in order move forward.

Where can I find a suitable forum for getting help?

Comment: Why not ask them here?

Comment: Asking them here is perfectly acceptable. :)

Comment: @Timmie - If possible, please consider closing some of your other open questions by selecting the best answer (if they have one). Consider which answers have been useful and need an upvote. We need users to maintain their questions so that the site can be an effective tool for the next person with your problems. For more details on best practices consider reading [the FAQ on asking questions](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 4):

- You can try on the Launchpad Users' mailing list:
  `launchpad-users@lists.launchpad.net`
- Or the `#ubuntu-packaging` channel on `irc.freenode.net`
- And of course, right here on AskUbuntu: [launchpad](/questions/tagged/launchpad)

Answer (score 0):

You can join #Launchpad on irc://irc.freenode.net, for instance.